# Sort a dictionary by list of lists in increasing order

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dictionary by list of lists. The items in the list of lists
are keys in the dictionary.

Something like:

```
sort_by_increasing_order(['d', 'e', 'f'], {'d': [0, 1], 'e': [1, 2, 3], 'f': [4]})
result: ['f', 'e', 'd']
```

My input list is:

```
[
['why', 'was', 'cinderella', 'late', 'for', 'the', 'ball', 'she', 'forgot', 'to', 'swing', 'the', 'bat'],
['why', 'is', 'the', 'little', 'duck', 'always', 'so', 'sad', 'because', 'he', 'always', 'sees', 'a', 'bill', 'in', 'front', 'of', 'his', 'face'],
['what', 'has', 'four', 'legs', 'and', 'goes', 'booo', 'a', 'cow', 'with', 'a', 'cold'], 
['what', 'is', 'a', 'caterpillar', 'afraid', 'of', 'a', 'dogerpillar'],
['what', 'did', 'the', 'crop', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'farmer', 'why', 'are', 'you', 'always', 'picking', 'on', 'me']
]
```

My dictionary somewhat looks like this:

```
{'to': [7, 11, 17, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 37, 39, 41, 47, 48, 53, 56], 
'jam': [20], 'black': [5], 'farmer': [11],
'woodchuck': [54], 'has': [14, 16, 51], 'who': [16]
}
```

What i have going is

```
def sort_by_increasing_order(mylist, myDict):
        #temp = sorted(myDict, key=myDict.get)
        temp = sorted(myDict, key=lambda tempKey: for tempKey in mylist, reverse=True )
        return temp
```

The output will look like this:

```
    sort_by_increasing_order(mylist, myDict)
    >> ['to','woodchuck','has','jam','who','farmer','black']
```

The commented line just sorts by the dictionary keys when i try to sort by the list.
My approach is not correct. The result should a list with increasing order of the length
of indices as mentioned above. Any Idea

Comment: Increasing order of what? Why is `f` first in your example?

Comment: i updated with sample dictionary. Increasing order of the length of indices in the dictionary etc. Does it clarify?

Comment: @user3247054 Can you add some more detail about how you want to sort the list? May be explain the first example.

Comment: @ashwini-chaudhary updated with sample output.

Comment: @user3247054 Sorry, I still don't get it. Please add some explanation, try to explain one of the examples. :) And why the key `'black'` is missing from the output?

Comment: @ashwini-chaudhary good catch. I added it in the output.

Comment: @user3247054 Currently I don't see what's the point of that list of lists, I am getting correct output using: `sorted(myDict, key=lambda x: max(d[x]), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to sort by the length of the list in the dictionary. This is how you would do that:

```
def sort_by_increasing_order(l, d):
    return sorted(l, key=lambda i: len(d[i]))
```

I would however recommend that you use a clearer naming scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your suggestion doesn't work. I get this error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. I have list of list.

Comment: @user3247054: You're not passing in a list of lists in the example.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon that's just to convey the point what i am trying to achieve etc, that's why i gave sample of my input lists and dictionary to clarify etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just used your input list to achieve it...

```
source = [
['why', 'was', 'cinderella', 'late', 'for', 'the', 'ball', 'she', 'forgot', 'to', 'swing', 'the', 'bat'],
['why', 'is', 'the', 'little', 'duck', 'always', 'so', 'sad', 'because', 'he', 'always', 'sees', 'a', 'bill', 'in', 'front', 'of', 'his', 'face'],
['what', 'has', 'four', 'legs', 'and', 'goes', 'booo', 'a', 'cow', 'with', 'a', 'cold'], 
['what', 'is', 'a', 'caterpillar', 'afraid', 'of', 'a', 'dogerpillar'],
['what', 'did', 'the', 'crop', 'say', 'to', 'the', 'farmer', 'why', 'are', 'you', 'always', 'picking', 'on', 'me']
]

# words you want to order in order of their number ov appearances
words = ['to','woodchuck','has','jam','who','farmer']

sorted(words, key = lambda word: sum(1 for lst in source if word in lst), reverse=True)

Out[38]: ['to', 'has', 'farmer', 'woodchuck', 'jam', 'who']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why sum and why 1 in sum. Can you please explain. I think black should be there.

Comment: @user3247054 I add `1` every time there is a list containing this word. Or I count the lists containing this word, thats what `sum(...)` does... (Helpful? More explanation?)

Answer (score 0):

In your code list comprehension syntax error, Try this,

```
def sort_by_increasing_order(mylist, myDict):
        temp = sorted(myDict, key=lambda tempKey: [tempKey for tempKey in mylist], reverse=True )
        return temp
```

Comment: It fixed the syntax error, but i am not getting the result which has highest order etc.