# Convert set to a list

Tags: python, list, set

I am doing a set intersection of two lists and get a set as a result.

```
temp_set = set([('a', 'p', 'p', 'l','e')])
```

If i try to convert it to a list like this

```
my_list = [list(t) for t in temp_set ]
```

I get a list of lists like this

```
[['a', 'p', 'p', 'l','e']]
```

I even tried:

```
my_list = list(temp_set)
```

but didn't get the intended result.

what i want is a list like

```
my_list = ['apple']
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> s = set([('a', 'p', 'p', 'l','e')])
>>> ''.join(y for x in s for y in x)
'apple'
```

or:

```
>>> [''.join(x) for x in s]
['apple']
>>> s = set([('w', 'h', 'a', 't'), ('w', 'i', 'l','l')])
>>> [''.join(x) for x in s]
['what', 'will']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if i have a set like this.
set([('w', 'h', 'a', 't'), ('w', 'i', 'l','l')])

Comment: @user3247054 What will be the expected output for that? (note that sets don't have any order, so iteration over a set may return items in arbitrary order)

Comment: It would be ['what', 'will'] etc or [['what'],['will']].

Comment: @user3247054 My second solution will work fine for this input.

Comment: you might be able to answer my this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446935/sort-a-dictionary-by-list-of-lists-in-increasing-order . I have spent a lot of time researching and find a correct answer, but was unable to get one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
In[30]: reduce(lambda m, n: m+n, list(temp_set)[0])
Out[30]: 'apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird line:

```
temp_set = set([('a', 'p', 'p', 'l','e')])
```

it is making a set out of a list which has a single element, the tuple `('a', 'p', 'p', 'l','e')`. Why that extra level?

A [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) is a data structure with *unique* elements. I think it has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Even in the `('w', 'h', 'a', 't'), ('w', 'i', 'l','l')` case, you probably don't want a set, but a list, unless you are worried about (and want to eliminate) duplicate words (perhaps you do, but it's not clear). A list suffices:

```
>>> s = [('w', 'h', 'a', 't'), ('w', 'i', 'l','l')]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in s]
['what', 'will']
>>> s = [('w', 'h', 'a', 't'), ('w', 'i', 'l','l'), ('w', 'h', 'a', 't')]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in s]   ### allow duplicates since it's a list
['what', 'will', 'what']
>>> s = set([('w', 'h', 'a', 't'), ('w', 'i', 'l','l'), ('w', 'h', 'a', 't')])
>>> [''.join(x) for x in s]   ### remove duplicates since it's a set
['what', 'will']
```